# What is the subject of this sentence? "More women than men attended evening classes at the education center."

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> More women than men attended evening classes at the education center.

Is this a correct and complete sentence? If so, what is the subject of this sentence and why?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hello Simon and welcome to ELL. On this site, we expect people asking questions to show us that they've made the effort to answer themselves, and to explain specifically what it is they're unsure about. This helps us answer just your question, rather than explaining everything about how to identify a subject, for instance. What do you think the subject is? What do you already know about how to parse a sentence? Please use the "Edit" button and add this to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The subject is the phrase "More women than men".

It's probably easier to see if we replace that phrase with just *the women* and remove the final phrase:
"The women attended evening classes."

The phrase "More women than men" takes the place of the entire subject, even though it is a phrase.

The sentence is correct, especially in formal writing or speech rather than in informal dialog, and it is a complete sentence.